# Sending TCP packets to Fluentd

Tags: tcp, splunk, fluentd

In my Mac OS, With `fluentd` I'm trying to read tcp events and write it to local directory.

Below is the `td-agent.conf` that I have created to open TCP port and writing to local.

```xml
  <!-- td-agent.conf-->
  <source>
    @type tcp
    @log_level "trace"
    tag "tcp.events"
    port 2201
    bind "0.0.0.0"
    delimiter "\\n"
    <parse>
      @type "regexp"
      expression "/^(?<field1>\\d+):(?<field2>\\w+)$/"
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match tcp.events>
    @type file
    path "/Users/logs/outputlog"
    <buffer time>
      path "/Users/logs/outputlog"
    </buffer>
  </match>
```

To test, I was sending the tcp packages to the port (`2201`) using tools like `telnet` and `netcat`. But the terminal don't return after connecting to the ports. It stays there with out any response.

Checked the verbose of telnet / netcat. No luck.

I expect `TCP` to connect and get the data logged in `fluentd` logs. But connection is getting established to the port but data is not written into log or the control of tcp connection is not returned back to terminal.

Comment: Did you get the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your conf file.

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
```

https://docs.fluentd.org/input/forward